# How to calculate $E(\hat{Md})$ and $Var(\hat{Md})$?

Tags: variance, median

How to calculate $E(\hat{Md})$ and $Var(\hat{Md})$?

Where the estimator for median is found by solving Md from:

$$\int_0^{Md} f(x)dx=0.50$$

where $f$ is a p.d.f. of some distribution (e.g. Exp) and then plugging in the MLE of parameter(s).

Comment: In order to expect a useful answer you should be more specific with your question. $Md$ = median? $MLE$ = maximum likelihood estimator?! So,  $f(x)=f(x|\theta)$ depends on some unknown parameters $\theta$, which, in a first step you did estimate with MLE. in a second step you use the estimator $\widehat{Md}$, solving  $\int_0^\widehat{Md} f(x|\widehat{\theta})\, dx = 0.5$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theoretical answer: This will be tough.  If it's for a general $n$, your best bet may be to find the distribution of $X$ and then use order statistics (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic) to find its pdf, and compute its mean and variance the old fashioned way.

Applied answer: Bootstrap, bootstrap, bootstrap.

Comment: I wonder whether you might be reading the question as asking about moments of the distribution of the sample median rather than moments of the MLE estimator of the median (which is what the question seems to ask).

Answer (score 0):

Without more specific informations an exact answer seems to be impossible, since the two moments in question of your estimator do not necessarly exists.

However, I give a more intutitive answer which might help to lead to the correct argument (at least asymptotical).  Suppose the MLE $\widehat{\theta}_n$ is consistent for $\theta_0$ and $f(t|\theta)$ is continuous in $\theta$. Your estimator, properly defined, reads as $$\widehat{Md}_n = \widehat{Md}(\widehat{\theta}_n) = \arg \min \{x\in \mathbf{R} | \int_{-\infty}^x f(t|\widehat{\theta}_n)\, dt =0.5 \}.$$ 
One now *might* show that $\widehat{Md}(\widehat{\theta}_n)$ is a continous function and apply the continous mapping theorem in order to receive $$\widehat{Md}(\widehat{\theta}_n) \stackrel{p}{\to} \widehat{Md}(\theta_0) = Median.$$
Since $\widehat{Md}(\widehat{\theta}_n)$ converges to a constant in probability,  you should intuitively  have: $$\mathbb{E}( \widehat{Md}(\widehat{\theta}_n)) \to  Median$$ and $$\mathbb{V}( \widehat{Md}(\widehat{\theta}_n)) \to  0.$$ However for this to hold you need uniform integrability. For instance, you need to show that $$\sup_n \mathbb{E}(|\widehat{Md}(\widehat{\theta}_n)|^{2+\epsilon}) <\infty$$ for some $\epsilon>0$. While this condition will trivially hold if for example the parameter space $\Theta$ for $\theta$ is assumed to be compact, I don't see an argument in the general case without further assumptions.

For fixed $n$, you obviously need even more specific details of the quantities in question. My bet is that in your case the set $\{x\in \mathbf{R} | \int_{-\infty}^x f(t|\widehat{\theta}_n)\, dt =0.5 \}$ contains only a single element, while on the other side $f(t|\theta)$ and $\widehat{\theta}_n$ are known explicitly. This should allow you to find an explicit formula for $\widehat{Md}(\widehat{\theta}_n)$ which moments you might then be able to analyse.

---

To be even more concrete, using your "example": suppose $X_1,\dots, X_n$ are iid $EXP(\lambda)$, where $EXP(\lambda)$ denotes the exponential distribution with parameter $\lambda$. It is then well known that the MLE for $\lambda$ is given by $\widehat{\lambda}_n =1/(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i)$. Moreover it is easy to see that $$\widehat{MD}(\widehat{\lambda}_n) = \ln(2)/\widehat{\lambda}_n = \ln(2)\overline{X},$$ implying $$E(\widehat{MD}(\widehat{\lambda}_n)) = \frac{\ln(2)}{\lambda} = Median$$ as well as $$Var(\widehat{MD}(\widehat{\lambda}_n)) = \ln(2)^2 \frac{1}{\lambda^2 n}.$$

---

I really hope that I didn't solve your homework.